# How can I fix ripped wall paint?

Tags: drywall, repair, concrete, walls, paint

[image]

I accidentally ripped the wall paint on the concrete because I placed my mesh Wi-Fi on the wrong spot. The paint was only done a week ago and I'm wondering how can I fix this the right way without making the hole bigger.

Comment: Have to remove all of the loose paint, sand the edges and area of removed paint smooth and repaint.  Paint that comes off of a wall like this says it did not bond well to the wall.

Comment: Yeah, it's worse than that, likely the surface preparation was not done competently anywhere on the wall, which means the whole shebang is going to fail at some point.  And there'll be no quick fix either.  Everything above the bad layer will need to come off the wall.